# Callback is already called using async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Once `fs.readFile` loop through all files and get the matching data and push it to results, I want to call `callback(results)` so i can send response to client. I am getting an error with below code `Error: Callback is already called` HOw can i resolve this issue using `async` approach.

app.js

```
searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt, logFiles, function(lines, err) {
    console.log('Logs', lines);
    if (err)
        return res.send();
    res.json(lines);
})
```

readFile.js

```
var searchStr;
var results = [];

function readFile(str,logFiles,callback){
   searchStr = str;
    async.map(logFiles, function(logfile, callback) {
           fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
               if (err) {
                   callback(null,err);
               }
               var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
               lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                   if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                       results.push(line);
                       callback(results,null);
                   }
               });
            });
    }), function(error, result) {
         results.map(result,function (result){
             console.log(result);
         });
    };
}
```

Comment: try to reverse params: callback(results, null); in ok result

Comment: in app.js i tried to pass first err like `function(err,lines)`

Comment: yes but when goes ok, params is reversed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** this answer is an extension to [trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519195/1022914). So if this answers your question, kindly mark his as the answer!

You said: *Once fs.readFile loop through all files and get the matching data and push it to results* then I don't think [.map](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map) is the appropriate function for this, to be honest. This is for transforming every element from an array into another which is not what you are doing.

A better method would be [.eachSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) to read one file at a time.

It's a good idea to rename your second `callback` to something else e.g. `done` to not confuse yourself (and others). Calling `done()` is for telling that the operation on the file is completed as in we are "done" reading the file.

Lastly, be careful with your typos. The first one may have prevented you from getting into the last part.

```
var results = [];
var searchStr;

function readFile(str, logFiles, callback) {
    searchStr = str;
    // loop through each file
    async.eachSeries(logFiles, function (logfile, done) {
        // read file
        fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
            lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                    results.push(line);  
                }
            });
            // when you are done reading the file
            done();
        });

    // wrong: }), function (err) {
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        }
        console.log('all done: ', results);

        // wrong: results.map(result, function (result){
        results.map(function (result){
            console.log(result);
        });

        // send back results
        callback(results);
    });
}
```

Comment: with your approach i got the `results` to client side , there is issue lets assume if user serach `id0536` if any line contains this id it will be rendered the result first time , two issues # 1 if i search same string twice its pushing it same array and send as two lines #2 if i search with different string value it send results of first search .

Comment: @Mikey, well spotted, the double `callback` variable has confused me in my answer, which I will delete (+1).

Comment: @hussain, as your question has clearly been answered, please ask any follow-up questions as new questions.