# How to use promises using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

This is my first time i am working with promises , So i have use `bluebird` library to achieve my task, In below code i have string input from client that i have to search in fileSystem. So i have to loop through dir and check if that string matched with any file push that line to `results` so once `forEach` finish i want to send `results` to client. How can i achieve that task using promises ? error with below code

`Error: Unhandled rejection TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]`

app.js

```
   searchFileService.readFile(searchTxt, logFiles, function(lines, err) {
     console.log('Logs', lines);
     if (err)
         return res.send();
     res.json(lines);
 })
```

promises.js

```
function readFile(str,logFiles,callback){
   searchStr = str;
    return Promise.map(logFiles, function(logfile) {

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                               if (err) {
                                   callback(null,err);
                                   return; // **** Make sure not to run the code below!
                               }
                               var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
                               lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                                   if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                                       results.push(line);
                                   }
                               });
                            });
        })
    });
//}
}
Promise
    .all(readFile())
    .then(function() {
        console.log('done');
        callback(results);
    });
```

Comment: You forgot to add arguments when you are calling readFile()!

Comment: those params i am getting from client , how can i pass it to promise it will throw undefined when i will start application.

Comment: Personally, I find promises are ugly as hell. [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) is way cleaner to read and understand.

Comment: hmm I was using Async but i could not resolve issue with that , see here question asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519121/callback-is-already-called-using-async?noredirect=1#comment72175283_42519121

Comment: @Mikey error handling in nodebacks is even uglier than hell, and there's nothing in async.js that relieves us of them.

Comment: @hussain That's because every [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42519195/1022914) is calling the `callback` incorrectly. You probably won't see my edit, but the arguments are supposed to be used as `callback(err);` and `callback(null, results);`.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

I posted some general advice and then some answers were posted with code examples that are quite complicated so I'd like to add that using the right modules your `readFiles()` function can be quite compact:

```
function readFiles(str, files) {
  return Promise.all(files.map(
    file => rsp(fs.readFile(`logs/dit/${file}`, 'utf-8'))
       .split('\n').filter(l => l.includes(str))))
       .then(a => [].concat(...a));
}
```

The right modules being [`mz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz) and [`rsp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsp) here (disclaimer, I'm the author of the `rsp` module so I'm clearly biased here).
The `mz` module lets you use promised versions of `fs` methods and the `rsp` module lets you invoke methods on promise results in the future.

You need to use those modules as:

```
let fs = require('mz/fs');
let rsp = require('rsp');
```

The `readFiles()` function above can be used as:

```
readFiles('line 3', ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'])
  .then(lines => console.log(lines.join('\n')))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
```

and it actually works - I tested it with a bunch of files the the `logs/dit` directory.

### Full example

```
let fs = require('mz/fs');
let rsp = require('rsp');

function readFiles(str, files) {
  return Promise.all(files.map(
    file => rsp(fs.readFile(`logs/dit/${file}`, 'utf-8'))
       .split('\n').filter(l => l.includes(str))))
       .then(a => [].concat(...a));
}

readFiles('line 3', ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'])
  .then(lines => console.log(lines.join('\n')))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
```

### Summary

As you can see no loops are needed, no explicit callbacks, no `new Promise()` construction etc.

### Original answer

If you want to use Promises with file system access in Node then use on of those modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promise
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promised

Or use Bluebird's promisyfyAll:

- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

to promisify the `fs` module in Node.

For example with `mz` you will be able to do things like:

```
return Promise.map(logFiles, file => fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + file, 'utf-8'));
```

to return a promise of the array of all those files contents in one line of code.

You can chain in further with:

```
return Promise.map(...).then(files => ...);
```

to get all files and work with them, or you can use something like:

```
return Promise.map(logFiles, file => fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + file, 'utf-8').then(content => {...});
```

and have a promise of an array of files contents after transformations.

Comment: That `rsp` library - making a proxy for the eventual promise value - is a really nice idea, but imo will only lead to total confusion, especially in newbies. It mixes the types of `Promise<A>` and `A` - and the documentation isn't even clear about how that happens. What if my [promise has a `map` method](http://blog.briancavalier.com/creed/#api-transform-promises-map-promise-e-a-a-b-promise-e-b), will `rsp(resolve([])).map(…)` invoke the array or the promise method? It definitely lacks a way to get back to "plain" promise from the proxy.

Comment: Also, the [`rsp` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsp) compares itself against the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) - of course it only can win! The proper way of writing would be `var promise2 = promise1.then(s => s.toUpperCase()); var promise3 = promise2.then(s => s.split('').join('-'));` - where omitting `then` doesn't really gain a lot.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot for your comments. This is an early idea and certainly needs better documentation. I thought about the problem of calling methods on the real promise vs on the future value and have some ideas but haven't implemented them yet. Right now it's more like an experiment to see if it can be useful at all. Thanks for the constructive critique, I'll take it into account trying to improve the module in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call "resolve", and you forgot to pass arguments, and it seems that you are using "results" as a global variable, which is bad.

Here's my correction of the code:

```
function readFile(str,logFiles){
   searchStr = str;
    return Promise.map(logFiles, function(logfile) {

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                               if (err) {
                                   reject(err);
                                   return; // **** Make sure not to run the code below!
                               }
                               var results = [];
                               var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
                               lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                                   if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                                       results.push(line);
                                   }
                               });
                               resolve(results);
                            });
        })
    });
}

Promise
    .all(readFile(searchTxt, logFiles))
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log('done');
        callback(results);
    });
```

Comment: How you are using callback if you are not passing it  in`readFIle` function

Answer (score 0):

The error *`TypeError: expecting an array or an iterable object but got [object Null]`* comes from passing no `logFiles` to your `readFile()` call, `Promise.map` will bitch about its first argument being `undefined`.

Also you must not use `Promise.all(readFile(…))`, as `Promise.all` does take an array of promises not a promise (which the `Promise.map` in your `readFile` function already returns).

But indeed, even if you fixed those, your code would still not work because you're never settling the promises you create. You need to actually call `reject` and `resolve`, not some `callback`:

```
function readFile(filename) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err); // <--
            else resolve(data); // <--
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can use that function in your loop:

```
function findFileLines(searchStr, logFiles) {
    return Promise.map(logFiles, function(logfile) {
        return readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename).then(function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
            var result = lines.filter(function(line) {
                return line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1
            });
            return result;
        });
    })
}

findFileLines("…", [{filename:"…"}, …]).then(function(results) {
    console.log('done');
    callback(results);
});
```

Comment: so i should export `findFileLines` for app.js and call it from there

Comment: @hussain Yes, try that.

Comment: @Bergi Having seen a lot of your answers about promises I'd love you to comment on the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536130/how-to-use-promises-using-nodejs/42536416#42536416) to the same question.